# Can't convert String to Numeric Values

Tags: python, addition, string-conversion

I want that if a string is in the element it is associated to variable. The variables should be added, that's why I included the val4 == int(val4)+int(right1) condition for example. The right1 is always the new value that should be added.
if I do "val4 == val4+right1 " then it adds the values as a string, but I want that there is a normal addition and not a string chain. I tried the int() for example , but when I use it it gives me always the value 0. It is possible that right1 can be a sting, if there is an error.
How can I modify my code that the right1 values gives out integer that are added.

```
                        for element2 in element1.split(","):
                            left1, right1 = element2.split("=")[0], element2.split("=")[1]
                            if right1=='WARN:SD':
                                1==1
                            elif right1=='WARN:TPG':
                                1==1

                            elif left1 == 'LAN_PORT_2_MAC_ERROR_COUNT':

                                val4 == int(val4)+int(right1)
                            elif left1 == 'LAN_PORT_1_MAC_ERROR_COUNT':

                                val3 == int(val3)+int(right1)
                            elif left1 == 'LAN_PORT_2_RTP_DIS_RATE':

                                val2 = int(val2)+int(right1)
                            elif left1 == 'LAN_PORT_1_RTP_DIS_RATE':

                                val1 == int(val1)+int(right1)
                            elif left1 == 'INPUT_1_SDI_ERRCNT':

                                val0 == int(val0)+int(right1)

        tot.write('''@echo off
    echo ^<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" ?^>
    echo ^<prtg^>
    echo    ^<result^>
    echo        ^<channel^> PEQ SDI ERRCNT INPUT_1_SDI_ERRCNT^</channel^>
    echo        ^<unit^>Custom^</unit^>
    echo        ^<customunit^>Errors^</customunit^>
    echo        ^<mode^>Absolute^</mode^>
    echo        ^<showChart^>1^</showChart^>
    echo        ^<showTable^>1^</showTable^>
    echo        ^<float^>0^</float^>
    echo        ^<value^>'''+val0+'''^</value^>
    echo        ^<LimitWarningMsg^>Reached limit of errors,Warning State^</LimitWarningMsg^>
    echo        ^<LimitErrorMsg^>Reached limit of errors,Error State^</LimitErrorMsg^>
    echo        ^<LimitMode^>1^</LimitMode^>
    echo    ^</result^>
    '''
    +


and so on ....
```

Comment: can you maybe isolate the part of the code that is responsible for this? This is just too much for *"convert string to numeric"*..

Comment: 1. Can you give examples of what is actually in the `element` ?